# Real-time Android application

Tags: real-time-java, activity-recognition

I would like to build an Android app that process acceleration data and return result every 0.5 seconds. Are there any way to deal with the problem with out using native code?

P/s: I'm a newbie so please go easy on me!

Comment: As far as I know there is no way of doing this at user level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no official support for real-time Java on Android.

But, there has been some research/academic projects focusing on bringing real-time capabilies into the Android world, you should check out:

- [RTDroid: A Design for Real-Time Android](http://www.cse.buffalo.edu/~stevko/publications/jtres13.pdf)
- [Non-Blocking Garbage Collection for Real-Time Android](http://jtres2013.atego.com/program-files/thomas-gerlitz.pdf)